# How to set the link in a view slideshow?

Tags: 7, navigation, views

Currently,  I'm creating a xyz resort website. In my home page, I implemented a slideshow by using views. I want the slideshow to be clickable: When I click on to the resort image in slideshow it should go the respective resort description page.

Can anyone guide me on how to set the link in the view slideshow?

Comment: You will have those options in the Image Field settings within the view.

Comment: Thanks Gokul, can you be more precise as i am new to vie slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a little change in the slideshow view: Just link the image field to the content and save. Go to *Configure Field > Link Image to > Select Content*.

> [image: screenshot]